# RCP application display menus listed in ApplicationActionBarAdvisor

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I need some help in displaying the menus in my RCP application.I understand that there are two ways of displaying menus

```
1. By specifying the <extention point> in plugin.xml
2. By including the menus in the ApplicationActionBarAdvisor.java
```

I able to view the menus specified in the plugin.xml file, but unable to view the one's specified in the  ApplicationActionBarAdvisor.java class. Is there any setting I need to specify in the plugin.xml for it to reflect ? Below is the code in  ApplicationActionBarAdvisor

```
public class ApplicationActionBarAdvisor extends ActionBarAdvisor {


private IWorkbenchAction saveAction ;
private IWorkbenchAction saveAsAction ;



private IWorkbenchAction introAction;
private MenuManager newMenu;
//

// Actions - important to allocate these only in makeActions, and then use
// them
// in the fill methods. This ensures that the actions aren't recreated
// when fillActionBars is called with FILL_PROXY.

public ApplicationActionBarAdvisor(IActionBarConfigurer configurer) {
    super(configurer);
}

public void makeActions(IWorkbenchWindow window)
{

    this.saveAction = ActionFactory.SAVE.create(window) ;
    this.register(this.saveAction) ;
    this.saveAsAction = ActionFactory.SAVE_AS.create(window) ;
    this.register(this.saveAsAction) ;

    //this.introAction = ActionFactory.INTRO.create(window) ;
    //this.register(this.introAction) ;
    newMenu = new MenuManager("&New", "new");

}

 protected void fillMenuBar(IMenuManager menuBar)
 {

     final MenuManager fileMenu = new MenuManager("&File", "fi");
     final MenuManager editMenu = new MenuManager("&Edit", "edit");
     final MenuManager helpMenu = new MenuManager("&Help", "maskithelp");

     fileMenu.add(newMenu) ;
     fileMenu.add(this.saveAction) ;
     fileMenu.add(this.saveAsAction) ;           
 }
}
```

Any help on the above is much appreciated. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You specify the `ActionBarAdvisor` to use in your `WorkbenchWindowAdvisor` by overriding the

```
public ActionBarAdvisor createActionBarAdvisor(IActionBarConfigurer configurer)
```

method.

Your `WorkbenchWindowAdvisor` must be specified in the `WorkbenchAdvisor` by overriding:

```
public WorkbenchWindowAdvisor createWorkbenchWindowAdvisor(
        IWorkbenchWindowConfigurer configurer)
```

Your `WorkbenchAdvisor` must be specified in your `IApplication` on the

```
PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(display, advisor);
```

call.

The `IApplication` must be specified in the `<run class="application">` element in the `org.eclipse.core.runtime.applications` extension point.

You must be running this application or using a `org.eclipse.core.runtime.products` product which specifies the application in the `<product application="application"` element.

Comment: I have already overriden the CreateActionBarAdvisor method in ApplicationWorkbenchwindowAdvisor.code belowpublic ActionBarAdvisor createActionBarAdvisor(
   IActionBarConfigurer configurer) {
  return new ApplicationActionBarAdvisor(configurer);
 }

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this might be a bit late, but from what I can see you have forgotten to add your newly created menu managers, **fileMenu**, **editMenu** and **helpMenu**,to the **menuBar** menu manager in the **fillMenuBar** method:

```
protected void fillMenuBar(IMenuManager menuBar) {

     final MenuManager fileMenu = new MenuManager("&File", "fi");
     final MenuManager editMenu = new MenuManager("&Edit", "edit");
     final MenuManager helpMenu = new MenuManager("&Help", "maskithelp");

     fileMenu.add(newMenu);
     fileMenu.add(this.saveAction);
     fileMenu.add(this.saveAsAction);

     // these calls are missing
     menuBar.add(fileMenu);
     menuBar.add(editMenu);
     menuBar.add(helpMenu);
}
```